# Laravel 4 failing Auth::attempt with Hash replacement

Tags: authentication, hash, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to do authentication in a Laravel4 project, but it always fails.

Since I'm only on PHP 5.3.4 I downloaded a replacement Hash package that uses SHA512 from https://github.com/robclancy/laravel4-hashing.

I already have a Users table (the Password field is pre-populated with SHA512 hashes, shared with another app) and my login auth method is:

```
Route::post('login', function()
{
    $userdata = array(
                'UserName' => 'SteB', 
                'password' => '1234'
                );

    if (Auth::attempt($userdata, true))
    {
       return Redirect::action('HomeController@Profile');
    }                    
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('login_errors', true);
    }

});
```

I've also checked the SHA512 hash is correct using http://hash.online-convert.com/sha512-generator

This always fails (silently), any ideas why or how to debug it will be appreciated.

My Users table is:

UserID    int, Identity PK
UserName  varchar(24)
FullName  varchar(32)
EMail     varchar(64)
Password  varchar(256)

This is in an existing SQL Server 2000 database, I'm getting User info out of the DB for an un-authenticated page, so I know the DB driver and connection is working ok.

User Model in Laravel:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface 
{

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'Users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password');

//protected $fillable = array('UserID', 'UserName', 'FullName');

/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
            /*Now all lowercase to match $userdata as suggested on SO*/
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->EMail;
}
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Just found this article: http://laravel.io/topic/20/hashing-in-laravel.
Looks like it's not doing things how I expected, a base64-encoded hash with random salt, I think.

Comment: What is the meaning of "failing"? User cannot log in? Or is there some  other error?

Comment: @Andreyco - It returns to the root page (http://localhost/) instead of firing the Profile action on my Home controller. I've replaced the redirect::to('/') with debug info to confirm, but don't get any error or exception.

Comment: How do you store your passwords in database? Laravel's `Hash::make()` outputs 60 characters long string, so you should store it using VARCHAR(60), at least

Comment: @Andreyco - It's a varchar(256) field, my SHA512 hashes are pretty long (128 chars I think).

Comment: really need more to go on for this

Comment: @Robbo - Anything I can provide just ask, I've got a feeling it's something I'm missing in the Laravel 4 config somewhere.

Comment: add 
`\Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($s, $b) { var_dump($s, $b); });` This will list out the query and you can see what it is actually doing.

Comment: @CodyCovey - I'm new to Laravel, add it to which config file?

Comment: Just add it above the `if (Auth::attempt($userdata, true)` line and after you build the array of username and password.

Comment: @CodyCovey - Added it to routes, got: string(67) "select top 1 * from [Users] where [UserName] = ? and [Password] = ?" array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "SteB" [1]=> string(4) "1234" }

Comment: It doesn't look like it is hashing the password?

Comment: we have come to the conclusion your model is wrong, show us please (if you use the eloquent driver)

Comment: @Robbo - Added model to question. Ran Hash::make('1234'), get "$6$rounds=5000$Qlin9FwzAoSYAbZV$M9JbunBl5NQ9OFKJVep1xR5hk0WBenfVtQ7ZrHOeZmHAlu1ak6nVOSuB5d3Gd.MsAooNM.3sO1hr69fRudn/e0" and it changes as stated in the article by Shawn McCool I linked to. The SHA512 hash of 1234 is: D404559F602EAB6FD602AC7680DACBFAADD13630335E951F097AF3900E9DE176B6DB28512F2E000B9D04FBA5133E8B1C6E8DF59DB3A8AB9D60BE4B97CC9E81DB

Comment: Cody has provided you with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to change something in your model as well as the key you pass to attempt

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface
{
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->Password;
    }

    // leave other code the same
 }
```

And in your array you pass change it like follows.

```
$userdata = array( 'UserName' => 'SteB', 'password' => '1234');
```

The getAuthPassword() tells the Auth library your actual fieldname and setting the key in the userdata to all lowercase `password` tells the Auth library to hash that field.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your database structure looks like, but could it be that your username key isn't the same are you database column?

Maybe this will work:

```
$userdata = array(
    'username' => 'SteB', 
    'password' => '1234'
);
```

Cheers.

Comment: As I understood it all field names are case-sensitive, (apart from "password" field apparently). I've tried mixed and lower case for both fields, none worked.

Comment: can you tell use your database structure for users please?

Comment: @Robbo - Added User table def to question

Comment: capital P on password?

Comment: @Robbo - Yes. I know my code doesn't have a capital, but it did until I read a post that said it must be lower case. Gave a quick try with Password in code, didn't work.

Comment: Where does it say it must be lowercase? Your fields given to auth should match those of the database.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: you can try all this etc, but I think I just proved myself wrong right after writing this.

This issue is to do with your database column naming and a restriction in Laravel I believe. Looking into Laravel's auth component I find a few areas where it specifically wants `password` or at least the string to contain that exact phrase. So your database needs to use the `password` column or you need to extend laravel to change some things.

Honestly, you should only ever use camel case or snake case with laravel. Issues can come up like this one when you use something it will never expect because there is no logical reason to use anything else.

So easy fix, use better column name.

Harder fix is extending the Auth component to allow for your `Password` field.

Comment: Renamed my DB field to "password", got a "DomainException: Unsupported Password Hash Supplied", see my update to my question.